# Windows/C++: why are loaded module memory bytes changing at run-time?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, module, patch

I'm trying to detect whether a loaded module is being patched at run-time by a malicious process. In this case the module is an EXE being run.

My detection scheme is as follows:

```
MODULEINFO mInfo;
GetModuleInformation(myProc, myInstance, &modInfo, sizeof(MODULEINFO));

//

char* hash1 = hashBytes(mInfo.lpBaseOfDll, mInfo.SizeOfImage);

//.....some time later

char* hash2 = hashBytes(mInfo.lpBaseOfDll, mInfo.SizeOfImage);

//

bool moduleIsModified = compareHashes(hash1, hash2); //false == we're patched!
```

This worked fine at first...hashes would be identical if no patches occurred, and I could detect my own patches (bytes within the module address space changed with VirtualProect/CopyMemory) successfully.

However, I discovered that if I put the following code between the generation of hash1/hash2, the hashes will no longer match:

```
//char* hash1 = ....

std::ifstream stream(pathToModule); //this causes hashes to no longer match???

//char* hash1 = ....
```

Why is the creation of a file stream to a module changing the pre-loaded bytes of the module? My assumption that the module would sit statically in memory after being loaded (assuming no malicious patches) is obviously incorrect...but why? Is there a specific area of a module's loaded bytes that are dynamic?

Comment: Does `mInfo.SizeOfImage` include the data segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul Sanders' question pointed me in the right direction.

The .data segment of the module was changing during runtime, so excluding that segment from my hash keeps the result the same.